# Remove empty xmlns attributes

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

This is my input xml `<a><b><![CDATA[This is a text]]></b></a>`

This is my xsl

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
version="1.0">

<xsl:template match="/">
 <xsl:apply-templates select="//b" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="b">
 <xsl:choose>                                                       
  <xsl:when test=".='This is a text'">
    <e xmlns="www.example.com">
      <f>yes</f>
      <g>
          <xsl:call-template name="atemp"/>
      </g>
    </e>
  </xsl:when>                                                                      
  <xsl:otherwise>
   <d>NO</d>                                                         
  </xsl:otherwise>
 </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="atemp">
  <l>l</l>
  <m>m</m>
  <n>n</n>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is the output xml-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<e xmlns="www.example.com">
 <f>yes</f>
 <g>
  <l xmlns="">l</l>
  <m xmlns="">m</m>
  <n xmlns="">n</n>
 </g>
</e>
```

I want those `xmlns=""` in `l,m,n` tags to be gone. This code is part of a large Java project. Interesting thing is these `xmlns=""` are not being produced in my colleague's computer, even when we both have the same code. Here is the running code http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3NzcBtS/1

This is the output I want-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<e xmlns="www.example.com">
 <f>yes</f>
 <g>
  <l>l</l>
  <m>m</m>
  <n>n</n>
 </g>
</e>
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
<xsl:template name="atemp">
  <l>l</l>
  <m>m</m>
  <n>n</n>
</xsl:template>
```

to

```
<xsl:template name="atemp">
  <l xmlns="www.example.com">l</l>
  <m xmlns="www.example.com">m</m>
  <n xmlns="www.example.com">n</n>
</xsl:template>
```

in order to place `l`, `m`, and `n` in the `www.example.com` namespace.  Since the `www.example.com` default namespace is already declared on `e`, and since these elements are descendents of `e`, you'll eliminate the `xmlns=""` from these elements, as requested.

---

Or, factored out to `xsl:template` via a good suggestion from [@TimC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7585/tim-c):

```
<xsl:template name="atemp" xmlns="www.example.com">
  <l>l</l>
  <m>m</m>
  <n>n</n>
</xsl:template>
```

---

Or, factored all the way out to `xsl:stylesheet`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                version="1.0"
                xmlns="www.example.com">
```

Comment: You could also just add it to the `xsl:template` to avoid some repititon; `<xsl:template name="atemp" xmlns="www.example.com">`

Comment: Thanks for the solution. This works for my above example. But my actual xslt file contains many nested `call-template` statements like in this example - http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3NzcBtS/2 . Each time a I call a template, it adds those `xmlns=""`. Is there any other solution in which I don't have to edit the file these many times. Also, the  `xmlns=""` is not appearing in my colleagues output file even though we have the exact same project copy. Any idea why this might be happening.

Comment: @AmitSingh: You can add xmlns="www.example.com" globally to the `xsl:stylesheet` element if you'd prefer.

Comment: Colleague getting different results:  We'd have to see a [mcve] and have more details to offer an explanation.